# Creating a config for a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, configuration

I want my JavaScript class to be configurable from the outside. So, I created a private `config`-property and a `loadConfig`-method. My problem is, that when I load a config, it overwrites the config-property completely and not just the properties I defined.

```
(function() {
var config = {
    param: value,
    group: {
        groupParam: value
    }
};
function MyClass() {
    this.loadConfig = function(loadConfig) {
        if (typepof loadConfig == "undefined" || typeof loadConfig == "null")
            return;
        else
            config = loadConfig;
    };  
}
window.MyClass = new MyClass();
})();
```

When I load a custom config

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        group: {
            groupParam: "newValue"
        }
    };

    MyClass.loadConfig(config);
</script>
```

I want `config.param` to still be "value", while `config.group.groupParam` is "newValue".

Currently, the object is overwritten and after `loadConfig()`, `config.param` doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, jQuery has a great function called [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) which seems to be what you need.

You can check it out in the [jQuery 1.6.1 source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js) for example ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and "extend" => been a long time since I've been waiting to use these keyboard things once :) ).

Comment: @ApoY2k You could have tagged your question as `jquery` also then :). Happy to help BTW.

Answer (score 1):

It's overwritten because you're telling it to overwrite with this line in your `loadConfig` method:

```
config = loadConfig;
```

In order to preserve any values that `loadConfig` does not explicitly change, you'll have to loop through all of the properties in `loadConfig` and assign them individually:

```
this.loadConfig = function (loadConfig) {
    if (typeof loadConfig == "undefined" || typeof loadConfig == "null") {
        return;
    } else {
        var x;
        for (x in loadConfig) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(loadConfig, x)) {
                config[x] = loadConfig[x];
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @ApoY2k It will not, but deep looping opens up a bunch of new cans of worms. Will there ever be arrays, or just objects?